# Make transparent eraser in kineticjs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, transparency, kineticjs

Hi how to make transparent eraser using kineticjs or just using canvas.

I need to erase part of polygon which is over some image, make just part of polygon transparent and image should stay the same.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you show your effort so far or be more specific?

Comment: Check the markE's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need access to context's `globalCompositeOperation="destination-out"` which acts as an "eraser".  The KineticJS context does not give you globalCompositeOperation so you'll have to dig to get the "real" html canvas context:

- Put your image on the bottom layer
- Put your polygon on the top layer
- Put a custom shape on the top layer
- Use the custom shape to get to an html canvas context [context=layer.getContext()._context]
- Use `context.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out"` to "erase" the polygon and let the image underneath show through.

Here's an example of the shape object that "erases" to the image:

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/yv9qn/

```
var myShape = new Kinetic.Shape({
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  fill:"blue",
  drawFunc: function(context) {
    var ctx=layer.getContext()._context;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";
    for(var i=0;i<this.cutouts.length;i++){
        var cut=this.cutouts[i];
        ctx.fillRect(cut.x,cut.y,cut.width,cut.height);
    }
    ctx.restore();  
  }
});
myShape.cutouts=[];
layer.add(myShape);

myShape.cutouts.push({x:75,y:75,width:30,height:30});
myShape.cutouts.push({x:225,y:75,width:30,height:30});
myShape.cutouts.push({x:150,y:125,width:30,height:30});
```

Comment: On question, if I replace rects which are transparent with polygons is the order of points important.

Comment: The order of the {x,y,width,height} objects is not important.

Comment: I think if this rect defined with {x, y, width, height} replace with polygons which are defined with array of points {x, y} for example, is order of points in polygon important?

Comment: I'm not understanding, but here's an example using polygon points instead of rects:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/kr545/

Comment: cool, thanks, I used some other algorithm which is depending on order of points in polygon.
Thanks